# Using `each` rather than `for`-`each` loop

Tags: ruby, for-loop, foreach

*Learn Ruby the Hard Way* asks to rewrite a script:

```
    i = 0
    numbers = []

    while i < 6
      puts "At the top i is #{i}"
      numbers.push(i)

      i += 1
      puts "Numbers now: ", numbers
      puts "At the bottom i is #{i}"
    end

    puts "The numbers: "

    numbers.each {|num| puts num}
```

using `for`-loops and the `(0 .. 6)` range. The only solution I can find to work uses the `for`-`each` construct, which the author says to avoid:

```
    def range_loop(increment, upper_limit)

      numbers = []
      for number in (0...upper_limit)
        puts "The number is : #{number}"
        numbers.push(number)
      end

      puts "The numbers: "

      for number in numbers
        puts number
      end
    end

    range_loop(1, 6)
```

How can I write this script using the `each` construct?

Comment: Your description is contradictory. The author, while claiming not to use `for`, asks you to rewrite something using `for`, and the result you got, which uses `for`, is something the author tells you to avoid?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Range` object and `Enumerable#each` method for this goal:

```
(0...6).each do |i|
  #some code here
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `upto`

`0.upto(6) {|x| p "The number is #{x}"}`

Comment: `6.times { |x| numbers<<x }`. Redundant `each`.